# Make Development For Allowing Visitors To Change Style Of MVC View Page Permanently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an .net mvc web project. this web project have a lot of screen. But i have an problem with this screens usage. For example Students page,  One user wants Students page with different style and same time other user wants same  Personnel page with different style.  I want to make on page and then give to  the users this same one template page. And then all users can change page css attributes with their reqirements. Namely page is different to the different users. All users can determine custom css attributes on same one template page. namely one user who use personnel page can change styling attributes with own wishes.

How can i make this infrastructure development. Can i write server side code for this development.

Thanks for yor opinions.

Comment: well yes you can use serversided code to decide which `.css` file to put in the head of the document. You can also use clientside code by editing the DOM and setting a custom css document in the head

Comment: Can the user create css  with changing screen while using th screen ? Is it possible ? Can you suggest some tutorial or some example ?

Comment: yes you can try https://jsfiddle.net/wusrxjch/ , which basically appends a css string as a `<style>` element to the `<head>`

Comment: User play on screen styles (during this time , css file  will be created) and after he save the changes and then screen will  use this newly created css, always.